# Продолжить выполнение кода после события

Tags: c#, события, callback

Есть метод и после одной строчки должен вызваться колбэк, необходимо сначала обработать колбэк, а затем уже продолжить выполнение метода. Как это можно реализовать?

```
ri.Status = "InPosition";
ri.OpenPrice = Bars[Bars.Count - 1].Item4;
ri.entryDate = Bars[Bars.Count - 1].Item6;
ri.Profit = 0;
if (result.Item1 == 1)
{
    ri.Direction = "Buy";
    Plaza2WB.sendRequest(true, 0); // после этой функции вызывается колбэк
}

else if (result.Item1 == -1)
{
    ri.Direction = "Sell";
    Plaza2WB.sendRequest(false, 0);
}
dataGrid.Items.Refresh();


// Код дальше должен выполниться только после обработки колбэка



SqlWB.updateRobotFromSignal(ri.Id, ri.Status, ri.OpenPrice, ri.Direction, ri.entryDate, ri.Profit); 

if(ri.StopType == "Stop\\Tp")
{

}
else if(ri.StopType == "newStop")
{

}
```

Comment: В таком виде - никак.

Comment: А что за колбек? Можно AutoResetEvent подвесить и WaitOne?

Comment: @Александр я отсылаю в интернете на сервер запрос, если всё хорошо, возвращается ответ с результатом.

Comment: Написать дополнительную функцию, вызов которой делать в конце колбэка.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин да, я об этом тоже подумал, но тогда я из основной функции должен как-то передать объект `ri` в колбэк и потом в метод. Сейчас читаю, возможно AutoResetEvent будет хорошим решением.

P.s. т.е. в основном коде нужно что-то типа, `Мы не продолжим, пока не выполнится данная функция`

Comment: @Fresto передайте в параметрах вызова функции `Plaza2WB.sendRequest(false, 0);` или вы не имеете доступа к изменению кода этой функции?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Не имею доступа, у меня есть лишь её колбэк, об успешности функции

Comment: хм... а какие проблемы в хэндлер данные передать, если вы будете устанавливать хэндлер прямо в этой функции, то там можно будет прямо в теле хэндлера использовать переменные из функции.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин да потому что это слишком велосипед, мне по сути нужно просто подождать, пока функция выполнится и всё. И это я уже получил через AutoResetEvent) Но спасибо за размышления